# Selenium WebDriver passes text assert on debug mode but fails in run mode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am fairly new to selenium WebDriver , I have hit a snag when running basic test to very 'Successfully submitted' message on screen after clicking submit button. I tried with wait statement and also with wait until element exist but no luck yet.I tried with solution posted in similar posts but nothing worked !   Works perfectly fine in debug mode though. Here is the code snippet

```
        public void CustomerCreatesSupportRequest_Test1()
        {
            Boolean result;
            String customerURL = getDataParser().extractData("CustomerURL");
            driver.Value.Navigate().GoToUrl(customerURL);
            BB2HomePage HomePage = new BB2HomePage(getDriver());
            SupportRequestPage SRPage = new SupportRequestPage(getDriver());
            HomePage.supportRequestLink.Click();
            ReportPassedTestStepResults("Customer Creating New Support Request");
            SRPage.addSupportRequest.Click();
          
            SRPage.supportRequestTitle.SendKeys("Test Automation Support Request Title by Customer");
           
            SRPage.sendSupportRequest.Click();
            ReportPassedTestStepResults("Support Request button clicked. Before wait.");

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.Value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
       
            driver.Value.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
            ReportPassedTestStepResults("After 30 sec wait.");
            String strTxt = SRPage.SuccessfullySavedSR.Text;
**// THIS ASSERTION IS FAILING - ACTUAL TEXT IS TEXT BEFORE CLICKING THE SUBMIT BUTTON** 
            Assert.AreEqual("Successfully added Support Request." ,strTxt.ToString());
            Assert.That(driver.Value.PageSource.Contains("Successfully added Support Request."), Is.True);
           
         
         }
```

Comment: _`String strTxt = SRPage.SuccessfullySavedSR.Text;`_: Where are you getting `SRPage.SuccessfullySavedSR` from?

Comment: _`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.Value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`_: Where are you using the `wait`?

Comment: String strTxt = SRPage.SuccessfullySavedSR.Text;: Where are you getting SRPage.SuccessfullySavedSR from?  --> I am setting the '.SuccessfullySavedSR'  element in PageObjects class .                                                                                  public IWebElement SuccessfullySavedSR => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='mb-0']"));

Comment: RESOLVED - With implicit wait on ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement. Thanks